# Make function of generic class only accept argument that is same generic type but more constrained

Tags: swift, generics

I have a `generic` class that can be initialised as any type. I would like to add a function  with a single parameter that takes a value that is both of the class's generic type and conforms to the `Comparable` protocol. Type conformance should be enforced pre-compile.

I would like to do something like this:

```
class Object<T> {

    let value: T!

    init (value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }

    func doSomething<U where U: Comparable, U == T>(otherValue: U) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. You can't further specialize a generic type in a method - you'd need to add a top-level function for the behavior you want.

This is the reason `Array` doesn't have a pure `myArray.sort()` function, since there's no way to guarantee that the members of any `Array` instance will be `Comparable`. Instead, there's a top-level function with this signature:

```
func sort<T : Comparable>(inout array: [T])
```

Your top-level function would have a similar structure:

```
func doSomething<T: Comparable)(obj: Object<T>, otherValue: T) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For reference, this is possible since **Swift 2.0**:

```
extension Object where T : Comparable {
    func doSomething(otherValue: T) {
        // do something
    }
}
```